# Why does Doctrine need to know column info?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Im new on Doctrine, Im coming from Yii's ActiveRecord which I find very useful. Now i'm trying to switch to Symfony and people recommends Doctrine.

But I dont understand why I need to duplicate the information of my db schema in the Entities Classes with annotations, in Yii thats not neccesary...

What I find bad is that I have to remember to update the classes when I make a change in column definitions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the wrong way around. With doctrine, you create your class and tell doctrine how that class should look like in the database (this is done by the mapping configuration). Then doctrine will create the schema for you.

And whenever you change your class, doctrine will update the schema.

Comment: Thanks, what if I need to transform data and not just schema, how do I do that? (like fixing a bad saved data)

Comment: Then you get the object from the database, tweak the properties of that object and save it. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Hi, I meant a massive update... I think I would need to use migrations right?